# WPF - How to change design (position of elements) of UI

Tags: wpf

please how could I change the position of the elements in the UI, or choose a different design when the application loads?

It could be done using User Controls for each design, but the bad thing about this solution is that the same code will be repeated and I do not want that.

Please what would be the best practices to achieve this, it should be noted that the controls must have a name to use it in the code.

Thanks in advance.

Summary: This is what I want to achieve

[image: Desired design 1]
[image: Desired design 2]

Comment: please insert your code as code-block (I don't fancy typing it from screenshot to reproduce the issue). My suggestion will be to use DockPanel as layout root and change Dock on UniformGrid to switch layouts

Comment: So you want the button bar to move between two places, and you want to change the orientation between vertical and horizontal. How does that involve repeating any code?

Answer (score 0):

In WPF the layout is all XAML. XAML can be stored in a resource dictionary. So once you determine what layout you want you can load the correct resource dictionary. Basically this pattern is exactly like people loading themes to change the colors of a UI etc.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a situation similar to yours. 
In your case, you should design your grid first as follows,

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding LeftButtonColWidth}"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding RightMainPanelColWidth}"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height = "32"/>
    <RowDefinition Height = "*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height = "{Binding ightMainPanelBottomButtonRowHeight}"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Then add properties "`LeftButtonColWidth`", "`RightMainPanelColWidth`" and "`RightMainPanelBottomButtonRowHeight`" in viewmodel to control your layout based on some setting specified by end-users somewhere.

The above code is just for main container. 
You also need a container grid for Buttons which should be designed as the main container grid using Binding property. In button container, you need bind Grid.Row and Grid.Column to properties "`ButtonContainerRow`" and "`ButtonContainerCol`" in ViewModel, they will be changed based on the some specific setting, when the app starts.

This is my solution. There must be other better solutions. 
I hope someone can give me a solution only using xmal. That would be the perfect one.

Comment: Respected sir, please could put some code, I would appreciate it ... as I said I want something similar to: <Grid  design ="{Load DesignN}" ...>